# 3 column responsive (changin column order)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

**Website link:** http://austinfertilityobgyncenter.com/about/

**Problem statement:**

This is basically a three columns website. (Some pages have only two columns)
I want to reorder my 1-2-3 columns to 2-3-1 for mobiles and tablets.

I read some answers on stackoverflow, but unfortunately couldn't find a solution by implementing those solution.

Is it possible to do this CSS? (I guess 'YES', note: I'm not so ninja with responsive designs :-/ )

If YES, Can anybody please suggest me how can I achieve that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is done in wordpress, can't you drag and drop the blocks around in your admin panel?

Comment: If you want to have different column ordering for mobile and desktop, you'll need to have 2 sets of the columns. Then with CSS, you can show/hide each set appropriately.

Comment: Mr. E got your point, yes i can drag and drop the position of the column in wordpress admin, but for desktop I dont want to change anything, I want to reorder columns only for mobile and tablets.

Comment: Can you user Bootstrap3 ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you don't just want to "change the column order", but also display them one above the other.

This is actually quite new in CSS. You can use `flex` for this :

```css
.panel-grid {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.panel-grid-cell:first-child {
    order: 3;
}
```

Wrap this in a media query such as :

```
@media screen and (max-width: 780px) {
    /* code */
}
```

I just tested this on you website and it works as expected. See more about compatibility on [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex)

Comment: YES, that's right. It looks like when i check it on my PC for responsive, it shows 1st block at last, but when I check on my I phone 5s - ios 8, I dont. Here is my code 

@media screen and (max-width: 1023px){
.panel-grid {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.panel-grid-cell:first-child {
    order: 3;
}
}

Comment: As I said, this is kind of new. Use prefixes for compatibility. See this http://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/

Comment: I tried that one too before posting my comment.
.panel-grid {
  display: -webkit-box;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
  display: -moz-box;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
  display: -ms-flexbox;      /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
  display: -webkit-flex;     /* NEW - Chrome */
  display: flex;             /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
}
.panel-grid-cell:first-child {
 -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 3;  
  -moz-box-ordinal-group: 3;     
  -ms-flex-order: 3;     
  -webkit-order: 3;  
  order: 3; 
}

Comment: Nevermind, I found the solution for 5s... Here it is:

.panel-grid {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
}
.panel-grid-cell:first-child {
    -webkit-order: 3;
}

Many Many thanks Brewal..

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways you could do what you want:

## 1: CSS3 flexbox:

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/j16vc82a/1/

More Info: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.item1 {
    order: 1;
    width: 33%;
    background: #f00;
}
.item2 {
    order: 2;
    width: 33%;
    background: #0f0;
}
.item3 {
    order: 3;
    width: 33%;
    background: #00f;
    color:#fff;
}

/* for your media query */

.mobile .item1 {
    order: 3;
}
.mobile .item2 {
    order: 1;
}
.mobile .item3 {
    order: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="item1">1</div>
    <div class="item2">2</div>
    <div class="item3">3</div>
</div>

<div class="container mobile">
    <div class="item1">1</div>
    <div class="item2">2</div>
    <div class="item3">3</div>
</div>
```

## 2: CSS Floats

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/0wk0526j/

```css
.container {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.item1 {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
    background: #f00;
}
.item2 {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
    background: #0f0;
}
.item3 {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
    background: #00f;
    color: #fff;
}

/* for your media query */

.mobile .item1 {
    float: right;
}
.mobile .item2 {
    float: left;
}
.mobile .item3 {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="item1">1</div>
    <div class="item2">2</div>
    <div class="item3">3</div>
</div>

<div class="container mobile">
    <div class="item1">1</div>
    <div class="item2">2</div>
    <div class="item3">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for a descriptive answer. Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Try your this: You must reverse this divs in this order:

```
<div class="panel-grid-cell" id="pgc-4-0-2">
<div class="panel-grid-cell" id="pgc-4-0-1">
<div class="panel-grid-cell" id="pgc-4-0-0">
```

All this must have `float:right`.

Comment: I've used a page builder plugin by siteorigin. Those ID's are dynamically generated by the plugin. Again, I dont want to change anything in desktop version, just want to change positions in mobile and tablet version.

Comment: this will dont change desktop version ... it is just float column from right side. desktop will be like this. `float: right` have to be only in media for big resolutions but for small resolutions this will be in reverse order

Comment: But more importantly, it does not change the mobile version at all, because of the responsiveness (columns are stacked)

Comment: So try to look on your website from mobile-first view it will be more simple for you i dont know how to solve your problem sry :/